# Handle Remote Notification Receive in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I implemented remote notification in my app & it works fine!
But I am stuck for handle navigation from notification.

**When app is in forground--- Working fine**

`willPresent notification` method will be called & I handled navigation while user taps on banner

**When app is in background or closed completely**

`didReceive response` will be called

**Problem**: When I check status for both (background & completely closed), it shows me as **background** only, I am not able to differentiate both these states any how.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If your app is completely closed you recieve notification on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this process is completely managed by iOS that one cannot guarantee you differentiating the statuses. I recommend you handling the events regarding closing or sending the application background and write the latest state to a file. Then, you can read it anytime to understand the latest state of the application.